# Grunt filerev uses wrong sources with sourcemapping

Tags: gruntjs, source-maps

I just started using Grunt. I'm trying to uglify a set of files with Grunt, and then create a revision of that file (with grunt-filerev). Everything is fine, except the sourcemaps for the file.

I uglify my files into 1 file called shared.min.js. I also create a sourcemap for this file, and filerev creates a revisioned file and a sourcemap for the revisioned file as well. This means it will generate 4 files:

- shared.min.js
- shared.min.js.map
- shared.min.153987b3.js
- shared.min.153987b3.js.map

The problem is that the shared.min.153987b3.js.map uses shared.min.js as it's source, I think it should be shared.min.153987b3.js instead. As you can see in my Gruntfile, I dirty-fixed this with a task called fixFilerevSourcemap.

Then the next problem occured: shared.min.153987b3.js uses shared.min.js.map as it's sourcemap, I think it should be shared.min.153987b3.js.map. Should I dirty-fix this as well? Or is there a better solution?

I have the following Grunt configuration:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceMapIncludeSources: true
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          'somedir/shared.min.js': ['otherdir/file1.js', 'otherdir/file2.js'],
        }
      }
    },
    filerev: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      },
      scripts: {
        src: ['somedir/shared.min.js'],
        dest: 'somedir/'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-filerev');

  grunt.registerTask('fixFilerevSourcemap', 'Blaat', function() {
    var revisionedSource;
    for (var file in grunt.filerev.summary) {
      var revisionedFile = grunt.filerev.summary[file];
      if (revisionedFile.substr(revisionedFile.length - 3) == 'map')  {
        if (null == revisionedSource) {
          throw "No revisionedSource found!";
        }
        var mapData = grunt.file.readJSON(revisionedFile);
        mapData.file = basename(revisionedSource);
        grunt.file.write(revisionedFile, JSON.stringify(mapData));
      } else {
        revisionedSource = basename(revisionedFile);
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'filerev', 'fixFilerevSourcemap']);

  function basename(path, suffix) {
    //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/basename/
    // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // improved by: Ash Searle (http://hexmen.com/blog/)
    // improved by: Lincoln Ramsay
    // improved by: djmix
    // improved by: Dmitry Gorelenkov
    //   example 1: basename('/www/site/home.htm', '.htm');
    //   returns 1: 'home'
    //   example 2: basename('ecra.php?p=1');
    //   returns 2: 'ecra.php?p=1'
    //   example 3: basename('/some/path/');
    //   returns 3: 'path'
    //   example 4: basename('/some/path_ext.ext/','.ext');
    //   returns 4: 'path_ext'

    var b = path;
    var lastChar = b.charAt(b.length - 1);

    if (lastChar === '/' || lastChar === '\\') {
      b = b.slice(0, -1);
    }

    b = b.replace(/^.*[\/\\]/g, '');

    if (typeof suffix === 'string' && b.substr(b.length - suffix.length) == suffix) {
      b = b.substr(0, b.length - suffix.length);
    }

    return b;
  }
};
```